# How can I replace a specific word when it occurs only once in a given subset of data?

Tags: perl

Consider the dataset below. Each chunk begining with a number is a 'case'. In the real dataset I have hundreds of thousands of cases. I'd like to replace the word "Exclusion" with "0" when there's only one word Exclusion in a case (e.g. case 10001).

If I loop through lines, I can count how many "Exclusions" I have in each case. But, if there's only one line with the word "Exclusion", I don't know how to get back to that line and replace the word.

How can I do that?

```
10001
M1|F1|SP1;12;12;12;11;13;10;Exclusion;D16S539
M1|F1|SP1;12;10;12;9;11;9;3.60;D16S
M1|F1|SP1;12;10;10;7;11;7;20.00;D7S
M1|F1|SP1;13;12;12;12;12;12;3.91;D13S
M1|F1|SP1;11;11;13;11;13;11;3.27;D5S
M1|F1|SP1;14;12;14;10;12;10;1.99;CSF
10002
M1|F1|SP1;8;13;13;8;8;12;2.91;D16S
M1|F1|SP1;13;11;13;10;10;10;4.13;D7S
M1|F1|SP1;12;9;12;10;11;16;Exclusion;D13S
M1|F1|SP1;12;10;12;10;14;15;Exclusion;D5S
M1|F1|SP1;13;10;10;10;17;18;Exclusion;CSF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sub process_block {
   my ($block) = @_;
   $block =~ s/\bExclusion\b/0/
      if $block !~ /\bExclusion\b.*\bExclusion\b/s;
   print($block);
}

my $buf;
while (<>) {
    if (/^\d/) {
        process_block($buf) if $buf;
        $buf = '';
    }

    $buf .= $_;
}

process_block($buf) if $buf;
```

Comment: Elegant! Performance-wise I'd expect this to be very similar to @ChuckCottrill 's solution, perhaps even slightly better?

Comment: Thank you guys for all the solutions. ikegami, it would be an ease step modifying this to replace the word "Exclusion" when it occurs not only once, but up to twice? I tried "if $block !~ /\bExclusion\b.*\bExclusion\b.*\bExclusion\b/s;". It works, but replaces only the first occurrence.

Comment: Use `s///g`. `$block =~ s/\bExclusion\b/0/g if $block !~ /\bExclusion\b(?:.*\bExclusion\b){2}/s;`.

Comment: Might be simpler to count occurrences then. `my $count = () = $block =~ /\bExclusion\b/; $block =~ s/\bExclusion\b/0/g if 0 < $count && $count <= 2;`

Comment: @ChuckCottrill, Not true. The approach would be the same for that hypothetical format too. You must divide into blocks in order to count the number of recurrences in the block.

Comment: @ikegami - your solution would fail with a leading digit on a 'non-case' line. Chane a line "M1|F1|SP1;12;10;12;9;11;9;3.60;D16S" to have a leading digit, and observe the behavior.  (example: "1M|F1|SP1;12;10;12;9;11;9;3.60;D16S")

Answer (score 2):

As you read the file, buffer up all lines in a case, and count exclusions,

```
my ($case,$buf,$count) = (undef,"",0);
while(my $ln = <>) {
```

Use a regex to detect a case,

```
    if( $ln =~ /^\d+$/ ) {
        #new case, process/print old case
        $buf =~ s/;Exclusion;/;0;/ if($count==1);
        print $buf;
        ($case,$buf,$count) = ($ln,"",0);
    }
```

use a regex to detect 'Exclusion' now?

```
    elsif( $ln =~ /;Exclusion;/ ) { $count++; }
    $buf .= $l;
}
```

And when you are done, you may have a case left to process,

```
if( length($buf)>0 ) {
    $buf =~ s/;Exclusion;/;0;/ if($count==1);
    print $buffer;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Very similar to @ikegami's work but with far less regex magic. I think this is easier for a beginner to approach.

Comment: @Mikko Lipasti - thank you! making the solution approachable and understandable to a beginner was my plan.

Comment: "Far less regex magic" must means "no `\b`" (since the regex is trivial), which is a bad thing. He uses `;` instead in one spot (good), but not the other. He also has very poor coupling (`process_case` relies heavily on code outside of it), which makes it harder to understand, harder to maintain and more error-prone.

Comment: The OP did not provide a file specification, but only examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could think of. Assume you read your file into @lines

```
# separate into blocks                                                                 
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($line =~ m/^(\d+)/) {
        $key = $1;
    }
    else {
        push (@{$block{$key}}, $line);
    }
}

# go through each block                                                                
foreach my $key (keys %block) {
    print "$key\n";
    my @matched = grep ($_ =~ m/exclusion/i, @{$block{$key}});
    if (scalar (1 == @matched)){
        foreach my $line (@{$block{$key}}) {
            $line =~ s/Exclusion/0/i;
            print "$line\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        foreach my $line (@{$block{$key}}) {
            print "$line\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There're already many correct answers here, which use buffers to store the content of a "case".

Here's another solution using `tell` and `seek` to rewind the file, so buffers are not necessary. This could be useful when your "case" is very large and you're sensitive to the performance or memory usage.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open FILE, "text.txt";
open REPLACE, ">replace.txt";

my $count = 0;      # count of 'Exclusion' in the current case
my $position = 0;
my $prev_position = 0;
my $first_occur_position = 0;   # first occurence of 'Exclusion' in the current case
my $visited = 0;    # whether the current line is visited before

while (<FILE>) {
    # keep track of the position before reading
    # the current line
    $prev_position = $position;
    $position = tell FILE;

    if ($visited == 0) {
        if (/^\d+/) {
            # new case
            if ($count == 1) {
                # rewind to the first occurence 
                # of 'Exclusion' in the previous case
                seek FILE, $first_occur_position, 0; 
                $visited = 1;
            }
            else {
                print REPLACE $_;
            }
        }
        elsif (/Exclusion/) {
            $count++;
            if ($count > 1) {
                seek FILE, $first_occur_position, 0;
                $visited = 1;
            }
            elsif ($count == 1) {
                $first_occur_position = $prev_position;
            }
        }
        else {
            print REPLACE $_ if ($count == 0);
        }

        if (eof FILE && $count == 1) {
            seek FILE, $first_occur_position, 0;
            $visited = 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($count == 1) {
            s/Exclusion/0/;
        }
        if (/^\d+/) {
            $position = tell FILE;
            $visited = 0;
            $count = 0;
        }
        print REPLACE $_;
    }
}

close REPLACE;
close FILE;
```